# Route test failing on: NoMethodError: undefined method `values' for "/the/route":String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails, rails-routing

I'm getting a failing test that I'm having great difficulty debugging.

My test case is:

```
it "routes to #active" do
  get ("/parties/active").should route_to("parties#active")
end
```

My route is:

```
resources :parties do
  get 'active', :on => :collection
end
```

When I run the test case, I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `values' for "/parties/active":String
```

Full error output at: https://gist.github.com/1748264

When I run rake routes, I see:

```
active_parties GET    /parties/active(.:format)   parties#active
       parties GET    /parties(.:format)          parties#index
               POST   /parties(.:format)          parties#create
     new_party GET    /parties/new(.:format)      parties#new
    edit_party GET    /parties/:id/edit(.:format) parties#edit
         party GET    /parties/:id(.:format)      parties#show
               PUT    /parties/:id(.:format)      parties#update
               DELETE /parties/:id(.:format)      parties#destroy
          root        /                           parties#show
```

The test I am running is practically identical to the test for new generated by scaffolding:

```
it "routes to #new" do
  get("/parties/new").should route_to("parties#new")
end
```

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: I also found that using `get` in the `before` block causes this same error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're putting a space between get and the arguments for the method. Don't do that.

You have this:

```
it "routes to #active" do
  get ("/parties/active").should route_to("parties#active")
end
```

When it should be this:

```
it "routes to #active" do
  get("/parties/active").should route_to("parties#active")
end
```

Otherwise it's going to evaluate like this:

```
  get(("/parties/active").should route_to("parties#active"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a hash-style route:

```
{ :get => 'parties/new' }.should route_to('parties#new')
```

Comment: Brandan, your solution works. :-) In case you are interested in why my code was failing, it was due to the space between get and the opening parenthesis, as Ryan Bigg pointed out above.